# Opencart test if version greater than 1.5.1.3

Tags: php, opencart

How would I add an IF statement to check if the opencart version is greater than 1.5.1.3?

This is defined in the index.php as:

```
// Version
define('VERSION', '1.5.0');
```

I have tried: `if((int)VERSION >= '1.5.1.3'){` although when I convert this into an int it becomes empty.

Also I tried this with the same effect:

```
$this->data['oc_version'] = (int)str_replace('.', '', VERSION);
if($this->data['oc_version'] >= 1513){
```

Do I need to convert this into an int to correctly perform greater/less than calculations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(version_compare(VERSION, '1.5.1.3', '>')) {
    // CODE HERE IF HIGHER
} else {
    // CODE HERE IF LOWER
}
```

Though the 1.5.1.3 branch actually goes up to 1.5.1.3.1 so I'm guessing you want it to be that

Comment: Perfect, I had not idea that this function even existed.

Comment: Opencart could use a massive Wiki with documentation and API and all things.. it would help the product and community.

Comment: JohnMagnolia - now you do ;)

@TheBlackBenzKid - It would be beneficial for sure, but it wouldn't have helped with this situation

Comment: @JayGilford yes it could've. We could have version_compare() and version() wrote in the API doc library like WordPress Codex does. Then users could see examples of what command, functions, objects can do etc.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid - The only issue with that is that version_compare is a standard php function, not an opencart specific one - And VERSION is a constant defined in the index.php files, so again its not a function defined by opencart

Comment: I was thinking that eventually the OC team will get to a point soon where they have less extra features to add into OC and they can spend more time on things like documentation.

Comment: That's a lovely idea John, just don't get your hopes up :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried this recently and couldnt get it working as above, perhaps its a PHP version thing but I got it working with:

```
if(version_compare(VERSION, '1.5.1.3') > 0) {
    // CODE HERE IF HIGHER
} else {
    // CODE HERE IF LOWER
}
```

Hope that helps someone else. Got the code from here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php

Comment: Which PHP version are you using?